Are 2-tensors always diagonalizable?
It has come up as a "surprising" and "incredible" result in several subjects that some type of tensor is always able to be represented as a diagonal matrix if you choose the right coordinate system (eg stress, inertia). Is this a property of 2-tensors in general, or is this a result of constraints specific to each case?

This is a property of symmetric 2-tensors, and this is essentially the same statement as the finite-dimensional spectral theorem (the fact that a symmetric matrix can be diagonalized by a conjugation with an orthogonal matrix).
